Power Toys - How to assign function key + 0?
I am using power toys in Windows 11. I would like to be able to assign the key f-0 (function key + 0) to open chrome. Is this possible and how could I do that if so with power toys?

It depends on the internal keyboard layout -- some laptops use Fn + 0 for keypad character, e.g., division (slash) on the machine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager

There are some shortcut keys that are reserved by the operating system or cannot be replaced. Keys that cannot be remapped include:
The Fn (function) key cannot be remapped (in most cases). The F1 ~ F12 (and F13 ~ F24) keys can be mapped.


It is not the Fn key itself OP wishes to map, but Fn + 0 together.
